# mixing processing.js code and javascript code

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I downloaded processing.js in my pc, but im not sure if it is possible to write pure javascript code in it. basicly my question is, can i write processing.js code and javascript code in the same file?.

Comment: yes, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can mix Processing and JavaScript using Processing.js.

From the [Processing.js quick start guide](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#combineprocessingandjavascript):

> Because Processing.js converts Processing code to JavaScript, it's also possible to mix them directly. The Processing.js parser will leave JavaScript it finds within the Processing code unaltered, allowing developers to write a hybrid of Processing and JavaScript.

Why wouldn't you just try it out and see what happens?